# How to substring HTML characters non-escaped with Groovy in Play Framework

Tags: html, groovy, playframework, playframework-2.0

Solutions to unescape characters are :

`#{verbatim} ${mycontent} #{/verbatim}` or `${_news.content.raw()}`

But is there an easy way to substring HTML characters with Groovy in Play Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but :

- if you want to **escape HTML tags**, you can use
  `${mycontent.escapeHtml()}` or `${mycontent.escape()}`
- if you want to **clean** your string `mycontent` to get only the text, you can do your own FastTags, using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library, and do something like that :

  ```
  package tags;
   ...
  import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
  import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;
   ...

  public class MyJavaExtensions extends JavaExtensions {

      public static String cleanString(String s) {
          try {
              return Jsoup.parse(s).text();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              return null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

And you can use it in your Groovy template like that : `${mycontent.cleanString()}`